# Gte and Lte in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs and getting data from api, I am trying filter result but the problem is that LTE is working but GTE not working!

```
$http.get($rootScope.baseurl + 'api/hotels/', {
        params: {
            page_size: $scope.page_size,
            page: $scope.page,
            goingTo: goingTo,
            ordering: $scope.sortBy,
            price__lte: $scope.max_price_filter,
            price__gte: $scope.min_price_filter,
            star: $scope.filter.star,
            discount: 0

        }
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  If you are asking why `price_gte` isn't functioning as expected, you would need to provide the code for `$scope.min_price_filter` for anyone to know what is going on with it.  Please see [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

if I'm correct there is not params object with a GET request, and the problem seems to be in the backend not with angularJS. 
[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)
I hope it helped.